# nested set db2 retrieve single path

Tags: db2, nested-sets

I'm used to using nested sets in mysql and to retrieve a single path I would normally use the following :

```
SELECT node.treeID,
       node.name,
       node.lft,
       node.rgt,
       (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM docsTree AS node,
     docsTree AS parent,
     docsTree AS sub_parent,

  ( SELECT node.name,
           (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
   FROM docsTree AS node,
        docsTree AS parent
   WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
     AND node.treeID = :requestedNode
   GROUP BY node.treeID,
            node.name,
            node.lft,
            node.rgt
   ORDER BY node.lft)AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
  AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
  AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.treeID,
         node.name,
         node.lft,
         node.rgt HAVING depth = 1
ORDER BY node.lft
```

Now I have a need to do the same in db2 but the above query gives me the following error:

ERROR: A column reference in the SELECT or HAVING clause is invalid,
because it is not a grouping column; or a column reference
in the GROUP BY clause is invalid.

[SQL0122] Column
DEPTH or expression in SELECT list not valid.
Error Code: -122

How do I return a nested set path from db2?

Answer (score 0):

In the last group by, try using

```
GROUP BY node.treeID,
     node.name,
     node.lft,
     node.rgt HAVING (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) = 1
```

Comment: I thought so. I'm curious what happens when you remove the having clause, do you get the same syntax error ?

Comment: yes I just tried it and I get the same error with the having clause removed.